# Agile Web Developement with Rails 3.2 Listing Products page includes extra information

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, view

Hey everybody I am studying Ruby on Rails with the book Agile Web Development with Rails 3.2 and I have come across a problem that I do not know how to fix. I have created a products view with the following code in app/views/products/index.html.erb

```
    <h1>Listing products</h1>

<table>
<%= @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">

    <td>
      <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %>
    </td>

    <td class="list_description">
      <dl>
        <dt><%= product.title %></dt>
        <dd><%= truncate(strip_tags(product.description),
              length: 80) %></dd>
      </dl>  
    </td>

    <td class="list_actions"> 
      <%= link_to 'Show', product %><br/>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %><br/>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete,
                    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New product', new_product_path %>
```

This view created by the page displays everything properly but forces extra descrptions at the top of the page:

[#\n CoffeeScript is JavaScript done right. ...", image_url: "cs.jpg", price: #, created_at: "2013-06-22 23:34:33", updated_at: "2013-06-22 23:34:33">, #\n Ruby is the fastest growing and most ex...", image_url: "ruby.jpg", price: #, created_at: "2013-06-22 23:34:33", updated_at: "2013-06-22 23:34:33">, #\n *Rails Test Prescriptions* is a ...", image_url: "rtp.jpg", price: #, created_at: "2013-06-22 23:34:33", updated_at: "2013-06-22 23:34:33">]

I am not sure if this is standard Rails output in the development environment. Is there something incorrect with my code? I know this is probably an easy question so any help is appreciated. Hopefully I have included enough info in the description so that others with the same problem can easily find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
<%= @products.each do |product| %>
```

You don't need the `=` since you're just iterating over the products, not trying to generate an output from this statement into the resulting HTML. With the `=` you are basically getting a Ruby dump of the @products table (you've asked Ruby to take the output of the `@products.each` clause and inject it into the HTML between `<table>` and your first `<tr...>`). Instead, use:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
```